# Creating a dynamic coupon checker

Tags: c#, algorithm, while-loop

I'm trying to create a coupon counter that checks the availability of combinable coupons that can be used to get reduction of an invoice.

If the available coupons are equal to the needed coupons, there is no invoice needed.

Example:

Company XYZ needs to pay 100 dollars (amount is always dividable by 25 with 0 rest) for their invoice, but they can pay it using coupons.

One coupon is worth 25 dollars so I need to check if the company has 4 saved up over a dynamic chosen amount of months.

My coupon table looks like:

**Total_Coupon_Count**

- ID
- CompanyID
- Month
- Total_Coupon_Count
- Year

Example cont:

Company XYZ has 0 coupons in march, 1 in april, 0 in may, 2 in june, 1 july.

Company XYZ can save coupons up to 3 months before (so the coupons May, June, July)

The result of this example needs to be:

**3 coupons have been used (2 in june, 1 in july), 25 dollars still needs to be paid by client.**

What my program needs to do is to:

- Get the amount of months a company can save coupons for (in this case 3)
- Subtract coupons until they are 0
- Get the rest of an invoice and show it to the user

This is my code I have now:

```
        //While the needed amount of coupons for the invoice is smaller than the total available coupons 
        while(neededCoupons < cv.combinableAmount)
        {
            //We start at the earliest month we can go back to (this month - the combinable months)
            for (int i = int.Parse(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(DateTime.Now.Month - cv.monthsCombinable).ToString()); i >= int.Parse(DateTime.Now.Month.ToString()) ; i++ )
            {
                int amountForMonth = GetCouponAmountByMonth(companyID, i);
                if (amountForMonth >= neededCoupons)
                {
                    //The amount is enough, we can stop
                    Result += "Coupons used from " + new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, i, 1).ToString("MMMM") + " amount: " + amountForMonth;
                    //To save the data, we subtract the neededCoupons from that month 
                    SubtractCoupons(companyID, i, amountForMonth);
                }
                else
                {
                    //The amount for that month is not enough (or zero), we need to subtract it, get the remaining and continue to the following month) 
                    if (amountForMonth != 0)
                    {
                        SubtractCoupons(companyID, i, amountForMonth);
                        Result += "Coupons used from " + new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, i, 1).ToString("MMMM") + " amount: " + amountForMonth;
                        neededCoupons = neededCoupons - amountForMonth;
                    }
                }
            }
```

I haven't tested my code but I know i'm not heading to the right track since I'm not taking the following into account:

- Rest value if all coupons are used and there still needs to be money paid
- Will my code work in January next year?
- My while loop, should i go on in the loop until i have enough vouchers (of course not)

I think that i'm almost there however. I'm just wondering how I could implement a rest variable to check if at the end of the ride, all coupons have been used up and rest still needs to be paid.

Comment: Isn't whatever you have left over after you subtract all of your coupons your "rest" value?

Comment: You could say, but how could i specify my `while` loop then? How can i specify in my `while`-loop that i need to continue until i have no more coupons left and that the rest is there to be paid ?

Comment: Return the result of the subtraction from your `SubtractCoupons` method and use that result in your `while` condition?

Comment: `while (result of subtraction > 0)` ?

Comment: @RobertHarvey can't be used as the while is before subtracting anything...

Comment: @KahnKah: Do-while then? http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-do-while-loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to help generate and print an invoice, I created a couple of models as follows:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public int TotalCouponsNeeded { get; set; }
    public int UsedCouponCount { get; set; }
    public List<UsedCouponsForMonth> UsedCoupons { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (UsedCouponCount == 0)
        {
            sb.Append("0 coupons have been used");
        }
        else
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0} have been used ({1})",
                    UsedCouponCount,
                    String.Join(", ", UsedCoupons.Select(x => String.Format("{0} in {1:MMM yyyy}", x.Count, new DateTime(x.Year, x.Month, 1))))
                );
        }
        sb.AppendFormat(", {0} dollars still needs to be paid by client.", 25 * (TotalCouponsNeeded - UsedCouponCount));
        return sb.ToString();
    }       
}

public class UsedCouponsForMonth
{
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

An `Invoice` contains how many coupons were needed and how many were used. It also knows how to print itself in the desired format.

The algorithm for generating an invoice is as follows:

```
public Invoice GenerateInvoice(int companyId, int maxMonths, int couponsNeeded)
{
    Invoice invoice = new Invoice
    {
        TotalCouponsNeeded = couponsNeeded,
        UsedCouponCount = 0,
        UsedCoupons = new List<UsedCouponsForMonth>(),
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < maxMonths && invoice.UsedCouponCount < invoice.TotalCouponsNeeded; i++)
    {
        DateTime month = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i - maxMonths + 1);
        int availableForMonth = GetCouponAmountByMonth(companyId, month.Year, month.Month);
        if (availableForMonth <= 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        int usedThisMonth = (invoice.UsedCouponCount + availableForMonth < invoice.TotalCouponsNeeded)
            ? availableForMonth
            : (couponsNeeded - invoice.UsedCouponCount);
        invoice.UsedCouponCount += usedThisMonth;
        SubtractCoupons(companyId, month.Year, month.Month, usedThisMonth);
    }

    return invoice;
}
```

The idea is to start at the earliest month, check the number of available coupons using `GetCouponAmountByMonth`, and subtract them as needed using `SubtractCoupons`. Note, that I modified these functions to take as input a `year` and a `month`. Meanwhile, the total number number of coupons is tracked in the `invoice.UsedCouponCount` variable. The loop automatically breaks when the used count is equal to the number needed.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but is it possible that you didn't take the rest value in amount (when there are no more coupons left to be used for the invoice)? I assume your answer only takes into account that there are always enough coupons left for a company

Comment: I understood that there may not always be enough coupons. The "rest" value you are looking for is `TotalCouponsNeeded - UsedCouponCount`. The loop will break when either a) there are enough coupons used, or b) the total number of months is exhausted. In the `ToString` function you can see there is a statement to generate "X dollars still need to be paid by the client".

Comment: Sorry but I have another question, how would I change the code if I want to start from the current month and go back to the earliest month (start substracting from this month, and go back month per month).

Comment: Changing `DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i - maxMonths + 1)` to `DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-i)` should do it.

Answer (score 2):

I made some classes that correspond to the problem, and then a manager that can get valid coupons, oldest first, then calculate the invoice amount from unused, valid coupons. You can change the amount of months that coupons are valid for and the code will react as needed.

```
public class Company
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Coupon> Coupons { get; set; }
        public Company()
        {
            Coupons = new List<Coupon>();
        }
    }
    public class Coupon
    {
        public bool IsUsed { get; set; }
        public double Amount { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }



public static class CouponManager
    {
        public const int MONTHS_BACK = 3;

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns all coupons within X months not used by the company
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="c"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static List<Coupon> GetValidCoupons(Company c)
        {
            return c.Coupons.Where(
                t => !t.IsUsed &&
            (Math.Abs((DateTime.Now.Month - t.Date.Month) + 12 * (DateTime.Now.Year - t.Date.Year))<   MONTHS_BACK))
            .OrderBy(t=>t.Date).ToList();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Find valid coupons, subtract from invoice each coupon amount until invoice is 0
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="company"></param>
        /// <param name="invoice"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static double CalculateInvoice(Company company, double invoice)
        {
            double amountOwed = invoice;
            List<Coupon> coupons = GetValidCoupons(company);
            coupons.ForEach(c => {
                if(invoice <= 0) //we are done with coupons
                    { return; }
                if (c.Amount > invoice) //no credits to give
                { return; }
                invoice = invoice - c.Amount; //subtract amount from invoice
                c.IsUsed = true; //mark coupon as used then update in db later
            });
            return invoice;
        }
        public static Company GetMockedCompany()
        {
            //mock data
            Company myCompany = new Company();
            bool used = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < 215; i++)
            {
                Coupon c = new Coupon();
                c.Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i);
                c.Amount = 5.00;
                c.IsUsed = used;
                used = !used;
                myCompany.Coupons.Add(c);
                Coupon d = new Coupon();
                d.Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i * 4);
                d.Amount = 5.00;
                d.IsUsed = used;
                used = !used;
                myCompany.Coupons.Add(d);
            }
            return myCompany;
        }
    }
```

You can then test the routine with a mocked company, like so:

```
 double invoice = CouponManager.CalculateInvoice(CouponManager.GetMockedCompany(), 1400); //returns 1070
```